# Erro ao executar projeto no Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Quando compilo dá `sucessfull`, mas quando tento executar o meu projeto obtenho este erro abaixo.

Alguém pode me ajudar ou dar uma dica?

Uso o visual studio 2015.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Error Could not write lines to file "obj\x86\Debug\NomeDoProjecto.View.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt". The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.    NomeDoProjecto.View

Comment: Qual o nome do seu projeto? Veja o que o VS diz `The specified path, file name, or both are too long.`

Comment: Qual parte da mensagem não percebeste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O caminho do arquivo `FileListAbsolute.txt` tem mais de 260 caracteres.

```
c:\pasta\pasta\pasta\obj\x86\Debug\NomeDoProjecto.View.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
```

Tenta fazer ele usar esse arquivo em outro lugar eu reduz esse caminho.

Ele tem 260 caracteres, tem que ter no maximo 248. Tira 12 caracteres do caminho que funciona

Comment: Resolvido obrigado

Comment: Não deixa de marcar a resposta, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

O erro é por que o **caminho do arquivo é muito longo**.

Mova o projeto para uma pasta menos enraizada na estrutura de seus diretórios. Por exemplo, `C:/Projetos/SeuProjeto`. Desta forma você reduz bastante a probabilidade de dar esse erro de caminho longo do diretório dos arquivos do projeto.